# Spectrogram - Whitening out specific areas

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm generating a Spectrogram in C++ and plotting/showing this using matplotlib.

This is fine, however, I'm segmenting parts of the spectrogram and want to identify key interest points. The formula works something similar to this:

```
if(block >= threshold) then
  spectrogram = block
else:
  spectrogram = "0"
```

In essence, if the block within the spectrogram is above a threshold then the data for that block is captured at the particular position. However, if it's not then we just have the block contain "0"'s. The problem is when I plot this, it does not show "white" in the areas where the value is "0":

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pylab as pl;

data = np.loadtxt('spec.txt')

hm = pl.imshow(10*np.log10(data.T),interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',aspect='auto')
pl.show()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Is there a way to set so that the areas that are not of interest as "white" and only show the areas that are within interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try masking the areas you want white

```
data = np.loadtxt("spec.txt")
data = np.ma.masked_where(data == 0, data)
pl.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', ...)
```

Edit:

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random_integers(-1, 1, (10, 10))
masked_data = np.ma.masked_where(data == 0, data)

plt.imshow(data, interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow(masked_data, interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Second Edit:

To change the color scheme, use a colormap

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(10, 10)

cmap = matplotlib.cm.binary
plt.imshow(data, interpolation="nearest", cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Check out [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) for a listing of many of the colormaps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, does this not work. Just shows the same.

Comment: Could you see the edit. It works for me, so 1.) make sure you've followed my code, and 2.) could you please post a sample copy of your data?

Comment: Ooops, was looking at the wrong file ;)! Long day! Thank you sir, can finally begin to write this paper!

Comment: Apologises, do you know of an easy way to set the values that are not 1's to just grey scale? But, it depends on the strength of the values? For example, the higher the value, the more intensive the grey would be. Should I ask another question with regards this?

Comment: Yes, you should ask another question, but you could use a colormap.  See the edit.